# TypeError: variable is undefined; i get this error in specific pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have plan to put a text (vertically) in a div (should be center and be in black area[in border-left]). But I get this error (TypeError: variable is undefined) in some pages which hasn't this class name in their structure , in other word this div.class not exist on them .this code worked fine in pages which has this class name without any error. What should I do?

http://cdpn.io/qhGFu

HTML :

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:80px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="tree clearfix">
                <div class="​​col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <div class="tree-content WhiteSkin tab-content">
                        <div class="tree-pane tab-pane fade" id="A">
                            <p>
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tree-pane tab-pane fade in active" id="B">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum, Founder and Director at Company.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tree-pane tab-pane fade" id="C">
                            <p>
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tree-pane tab-pane fade" id="D">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum, Founder and Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                                John Doe, Director at Company.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="​col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="tree-panel panel-container">
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">
                                <li>A</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">
                                <li class="active">B</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">
                                <li>C</li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#D" data-toggle="tab">
                                <li>D</li>
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(window).load(function(){
        if (! $('.tree').get(0) ) return;
        $('<div class="tree-title" />').appendTo('.tree-content');

        $('.tree-title').text("Tree").css({
            "position":                "absolute",
            "top":                     "0",
            "left":                    "0",
            "color":                   "#FFFFFF",
            "font-size":               "18px",
            "-webkit-transform":       "rotate(-90deg)",
            "-moz-transform":          "rotate(-90deg)",
            "-o-transform":            "rotate(-90deg)",
            "transform":               "rotate(-90deg)",
            "z-index":                 "600"
        });
    });



    (function($){
        $.fn.tree = function (){
            setTimeout(function()
                {
                    var heightPane = $('.tree-pane.active').css('height');
                    heightPane = parseInt(heightPane);
                    var p = $('.tree-title').position();
                    var h = $('.tree-title').height();
                    var w = $('.tree-title').width();

                    var cal_1 = ((40 - h) / 2) - 1;
                    var cal_2 = (heightPane - w) / 2;

                    var _cal_1 = - ((p.top) - cal_2);
                    var _cal_2 = - ((p.left) - cal_1);


                    $('.tree-title').css({
                        "margin-top": _cal_1,
                        "margin-left": _cal_2
                    });
                }, 200 + 20);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tree').tree();
        $('.tree-panel a').bind("click",function(){
            $('.tree').tree();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: i was added codepen dear Nick Wilde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell if a variable is undefined, you may use

```
if (typeof myVariable == "undefined")
```

Since you are using jQuery, to verify if a class is present (and do the stuff) or not, use

```
if ($(".myClass").length == 0) {
    //stuff if class is absent
} else {
    //your current instructions
}
```

EDIT: in your case, **if you do not want that code to be executed if the required class is missing**, you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4K8t8/1/)

Comment: to better understand what is going on with your code, give a try to https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/ dev console

Comment: i test it before . my problem is why console.log say TypeError: p is undefined

Comment: on the right side of the console, at the same level of the error, there is the error's location, on which you can click to go directly to the script.

Is the error located into your own script or eslewhere? Try the controls I put in my answer

Comment: thanks nicolallias , your solution is very useful but in my case i just change (window).load to (document).ready and my problem solved. thanks again